# rails 2.3.14 + google adwords api = trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-ads-api

Project rails 2.3.14

```
gem 'google-adwords-api', '0.7.2'

bundle install
```

The error:

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem
 "rack": In Gemfile:
     google-adwords-api (= 0.7.2)  ruby depends on
     rack (~> 1.4) ruby
     rails (= 2.3.14) ruby depends on
     rack (1.1.0)
```

Is it possible to fix this issue without using newer version of Rails?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

bundle exec bundle install

Comment: Could not find gem 'google-adwords-api (= 0.7.2) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it without a specific version, to see if there are any compatable versions, like this `gem 'google-adwords-api'` instead of `gem 'google-adwords-api', '0.7.2'`.

Comment: That particular set of gems is not "officially" compatible, but may work. You could try something like this - https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/12 . But there is no guarantee that it will really all play nice together, for your use case.